# How to get JS Object in Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF)?

Tags: c++, chromium, chromium-embedded

Is it possible to get an existing object reference using CEF API?

For example I run a script using `ExecuteJavaScript()`

```
function foo()
{
    var self = this;
    self.value="some value";
}
var fooObj = new foo;
```

This script creates a new variable `fooObj`. It is possible to get a reference to this variable later in the C++ code and to modify its value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to get it by doing something like the following (untested):

```
    auto context = AppGetBrowser()->GetMainFrame()->GetV8Context();
    CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> p = context->GetGlobal()->GetValue(CefString("fooObj"));
```

You may need to Enter/Exit the context depending on where you're calling it from in C++.  Furthermore you may need to actually reference your object explicitly as 'window.fooObj' in which case you'll have to get the value for 'window' and then get 'fooObj' off that.

(edit - accidentally posted too early)
(edit 2 - more)

Comment: Got a breakpoint on GetV8Context on string cef_v8context_t* _retval = struct_->get_v8context(struct_); in frame_ctocpp.cc. Everything before context gets fine. I'm trying to use it inside win32 callback function. Maybe You got any ideas?

Comment: @SinnerSmile - It's been a while since I've done stuff with it but IIRC there's some kind of EnterContext/ExitContext thing on the browser that you need call if you're calling from a questionable JS state...

Comment: Yes, but how can I enter it, if I even can't get context to enter... it seems that I need to use onContextCreated() OVERRIDE, that will be triggere emmidietly, when context created, and do my dirty value assigning stuff there, got only assumption, how it works, will try and hope I'm not mistaken this time.